# The output of functorch.hessian is not understandable

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, hessian-matrix

I am calculating the hessian of a ( 2,2) linear model using `functorch.hessian` as follows

```
model = torch.nn.Linear(2,2).to(device)
inputs = torch.rand(1,2).to(device)
criterion = torch.nn.CrossEntropyLoss()
target=torch.ones(len(inputs), dtype=torch.long).to(device)

func, func_params = functorch.make_functional(model) 

def loss(params):
    out = func(params, inputs) 
    return criterion(out, target)  

H=functorch.hessian(loss)(func_params)
```

Since I have 2 inputs and 2 outputs so we have basically 4 parameters I was expecting to see the second derivative with respect to these 4 parameters but the output looks different or not understandable. For example, the output of the code above is the following:

```
((tensor([[[[ 0.0217,  0.0701],
            [-0.0217, -0.0701]],
  
           [[ 0.0701,  0.2266],
            [-0.0701, -0.2266]]],
  
  
          [[[-0.0217, -0.0701],
            [ 0.0217,  0.0701]],
  
           [[-0.0701, -0.2266],
            [ 0.0701,  0.2266]]]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>),
  tensor([[[ 0.0718, -0.0718],
           [ 0.2321, -0.2321]],
  
          [[-0.0718,  0.0718],
           [-0.2321,  0.2321]]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>)),
 (tensor([[[ 0.0718,  0.2321],
           [-0.0718, -0.2321]],
  
          [[-0.0718, -0.2321],
           [ 0.0718,  0.2321]]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>),
  tensor([[ 0.2377, -0.2377],
          [-0.2377,  0.2377]], device='cuda:0', grad_fn=<ViewBackward0>)))
```

Does anyone have an idea what's going on? and how can I calculate the trace of the hessian matrix in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Model weights shape:**

torch.Size([2, 2]) *<- w1*

torch.Size([2]) *<- w2*

**Jacobian shape: (first dim is your batch size)**

J[0].shape = [1, 2, 2] *<- dLoss with respect to w1*

J[1].shape = [1, 2] *<- dLoss with respect to w2*

**Hessian shape: (first dim is your batch size)**

H[0][0].shape = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2] *<- dJ[0] with respect to w1*

H[0][1].shape = [1, 2, 2, 2, 2] *<- dJ[0] with respect to w2*

H[1][0].shape = [1, 2, 2, 2] *<- dJ[1] with respect to w1*

H[1][1].shape = [1, 2, 2, 2] *<- dJ[1] with respect to w2*

It helps to notice that the shape of H[0] have the same first values than J[0], same for H[1] and J[1]. You are deriving twice with respect to the parameters, thus you repeat the weights shape again.

Comment: How would I efficiently get a symmetric Hessian out of this?